# How to set options of commands called by browser?

Tags: scripts, firefox, chromium, browser, espeak

Presently when [Speech Synthesis Markup Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-speech-synthesis11-20100907/) (SSML) is set as at `text` property of [`SpeechSynthesisUtterance`](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html#utterance-attributes) instance  at [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795371) or [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425523) web browsers the SSML is not parsed at *nix as reflected at audio output of [`speechSynthesis.speak()`](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/webspeechapi.html#dfn-ttsspeak) call.

When Chromium is launched with [`--enable-speech-dispatcher`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#enable-speech-dispatcher) flag `speech-dispatcher` is started automatically `man speech-dispatcher`

```
DESCRIPTION
       speech-dispatcher  is  a  server process that is responsible for trans‐
       forming requests for text-to-speech output into actual speech  hearable
       in the speakers. It arbitrates concurrent speech requests based on mes‐
       sage priorities, and abstracts different  speech  synthesizers.  Client
       programs,  like  screen  readers  or  navigation  software, send speech
       requests to speech-dispatcher using TCP  protocol  (with  the  help  of
       client  libraries).  speech-dispatcher is usually started automatically
       by client libraries (i.e. autospawn), so you only need to run it  manu‐
       ally if testing/debugging, or when in other explicit need for a special
       setup.
```

as reflected at Task Manager

```
speech-dispatcher --spawn-communication-method unix_socket --socket-path /run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/speechd.sock
```

Running

```
spd-conf -u
```

creates a user configuration file for `speech-dispatcher` within `~/.config` where

[`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) is set as the default module

```
DefaultModule   espeak
```

`espeak` has an `m` option

```
-m     Interpret SSML markup, and ignore other < > tags
```

Am not entirely sure if `spd-say` is not called when `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` is called; `spd-say` has an `x` option which achieves same result as above `man spd-say`

```
-x, --ssml          Set SSML mode on (default: off)
```

The [`speech-dispatcher`](https://devel.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/speech-dispatcher.html) documentation states that the user configuration file can be used to set parameters for specific clients

> **4.1.6 Parameter Settings Commands**
>
> The following parameter setting commands are available. For
>   configuration and history clients there are also functions for setting
>   the value for some other connection and for all connections. They are
>   listed separately below.
>
> C API function: `int spd_set_data_mode(SPDConnection *connection,
>   SPDDataMode mode)` Set Speech Dispatcher data mode. Currently, plain
>   text and SSML are supported. SSML is especially useful if you want to
>   use index marks or include changes of voice parameters in the text.
>
> mode is the requested data mode: `SPD_DATA_TEXT` or `SPD_DATA_SSML`.

Requirement:

Parse the SSML set at `text` property of `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` using the existing capabilities of the native program called to convert text to speech by `speech-dispatcher`.

Question:

How to set the default option of either or both `-x` for `spd-say` and `-m` for `espeak` commands at `~/.config/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf` for the clients Chromium (unix socket connect), and if possible Firefox, when `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` is called by the browsers?

Comment: This has already been asked by this same user at [U & L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413860/how-to-set-options-of-commands-called-by-browser).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user has already cross-posted on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413860/how-to-set-options-of-commands-called-by-browser).

Comment: @jokerdino What does "cross-posted" mean? Is not Unix an entirely different site with different users?